# it is possible to seek the http live streaming on android device

Tags: android

1.I have to use .m3u8 file for HLS,tried to seek the video as 0th position using video view but it is playing  live streaming.

```
videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://xxx.xxx.xx/test/640x360_main_656.m3u8"));   
videoPlayer.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
        videoPlayer.seekTo(0);
        videoPlayer.start();
    }   
});
```

2.I tested android version 4.1.1 is support to play from beginning,it is support android version based?

3. is an android Exo player  support to play video live streaming  from  beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you cannot** play a live stream from beginning (that's why it's a Live Stream) **BUT** you can tweak the server from which you are getting your live stream (most probably it will be a Wowza server) to enable stream caching than you can play the stream from beginning as server is caching your stream and will provide you complete stream from beginning.